# Iterate through dates and through columns using Model Builder of ArcGIS 10.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, loop, iteration

I have a point feature class in a geodatabase (approx 11000 features) with 366 columns.  From these, one represents the targeted date and the other 365 represents the temperature of one day of the year. I added a new column named “Temperature” and I would like to fill in this column with the corresponding temperature value of my date field.
 Hard to explain, here's an example:

```
DateFin   b1_T_M01     b2_T_M0   Temperature
01-01-18    5.6           3.8       5.6  
06-01-18    5.6           4.2
02-01-18    6.3           4.6       4.6
20-01-18    6.3           4.6
20-01-18    6.3           4.6
27-01-18    5.9           4.2
```

From `bx_TMx`:  the `b` refers to the day and `M` to the month. So for example `b1_T_M01` refers to the temperature value of day one of the month one (first of January) .

As I said before, instead of having so many dimensions, I would like to have only the temperature field and add the corresponding value to this field `DateFin`.
As example: for date 27-01-18 I would need the *band 27* from the *month* 01 (b27_TM01).

That said, does anyone have a clue of how to do that with a Model Builder in ArcGIS, in an iterative way (without having to do it one by one per hand).

Comment: I can add an arcpy solution if you are ok with that? `DateFin` field is date data type or text?

Comment: yeah! that would be helpful! Thanks @BERA

Comment: You *can't* have a shapefile with 366 columns, because dBase uses a 1-byte field to store `nFields` (the spec restricts the format to 100 fields, but most vendors ignore that). "ArcGIS 10.x" is a multiple generations of software. Please [Edit] the question to specify the actual data format and *exact* release in use. This task could be accomplished with 20 lines of ArcPy code, 15 of which are in the documentation; ModelBuilder doesn't seem the right tool.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it. You are right!  I put it in a geodatabase and everything is ok now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arcpy. You might need to adjust the code:

```py
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\testdatabas.gdb\dates' #Change to match your data 
bfields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.name.startswith('b')] #List the 365 "b-fields"
all_fields = bfields+['DateFin','Temperature'] #Add the two other

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,all_fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        field_to_find = 'b{}_T_M{}'.format(row[-2].month, row[-2].day) #Create a string to search for
        if field_to_find in all_fields:
            index_of_field = all_fields.index(field_to_find) #Fetch index of the field
            row[-1] = row[index_of_field] #Update last field in list ('Temperature')
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will try it right away.